# How to recover files from an .ost?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap

When I search for this question on Google I find many results, but none of them seem to work for me. Here's my situation:

I use an online mail box via IMAP. I accidentally forgot to move a folder when I moved to another server. The old mail box is lost.

The folder can be recovered from a backup of the old .ost. I know it works because I can open it with the trial version of PST Walker (http://www.pstwalker.com/) but I don't want to buy any software. I do not have the data within Outlook because I reinstalled my laptop.

Is there someway I can convert the file to a .pst? Switching the file with my current .ost doesn't work either.

Further info:
It is not a MS Exchange Server. I use Outlook 2016, the .ost was likely created with Outlook 2013.

Comment: As a general practice, your first sentence isn't helpful to finding a solution.  Without knowing specifically what you already researched and tried, people are likely to waste time recommending things you've already discarded.